# DialogFlow ES: how to retrieve the confidence score?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

How to capture the confidence score for the utterance spoken on DialogFlow side ? I can see "intentDetectionConfidence" but it's always coming as "1".

Any idea or suggestion ?

Thanks,
Gagan

Answer (score 0):

The confidence score values range from *0.0 (completely uncertain)* to *1.0 (completely certain)*. You are getting the value of 1 means that the "intentDetectionConfidence" for the utterance spoken is **completely certain**.

You may refer to [Intent detection confidence Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-matching#confidence) for more details.